# What do the reputation percentage values in the System Panel mean?

Tags: elite-dangerous

On the System Panel of your ship

[image]

There is a list of Reputations that indicate your current status with a faction; this is all fine (and skipped over entirely in the manual)

However there is a second page to this Reputation screen where the various factions for the system are indicated as percentages along with up/down delta change indicators

What do these percentages mean?

Are they your rep with the factions?
The factions control of the local system?
The factions status with the controlling faction?
The factions popularity with Dave the Dog?
Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those percentages are that faction's influence/control in the system. The delta arrows show if their influence is changing (I think only changeable by mass player action).

Your rep with the faction is the "neutral" text, with only 5 levels and any range within those levels not really visible.